# Chrome Extension + Webcam

Tags: flash, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Am new with the extensions and I want to create an extension for Chrome that can capture video from a webcam (flash player I guess) and run some event when the cam capture some move or input (this is not the point here). For example I want to change the current URL in the browser.

My question is which is the best approach to create this kind of "deamon" to run "in background" on the browser?

I hope my twisted question was clear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html and http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 21 stable is just launched.  It includes the getUserMedia API, which let your javascript and HTML access the webcam without using Flash nor any plugin at all.

getUserMEdia how to:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Chromium introducing getUserMedia:
http://blog.chromium.org/2012/07/introducing-getusermedia-and-javascript.html

If your Chrome is not already upgraded to v21, you can download and install it to force the update.